# #2006 - MySQL server has gone away when restoring mysql dump

Tags: mysql

Environment : Windows 7
XAMPP 1.7.3

I have gone through Many stackoverflow solution for this problem and changed setting in file

> `my.ini`

which now looks like

```
 # Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is @localstatedir@) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#user       = your_username
#password   = your_password
host        = .
port        = 3306
socket      = "MySQL"

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
basedir                 = "D:/Program Files/xampp/mysql/"
datadir                 = "D:/Program Files/xampp/mysql/data/"
port                    = 3306
socket                  = "MySQL"
skip-locking
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 254M
table_cache             = 64
sort_buffer_size        = 512K
net_buffer_length       = 8K
read_buffer_size        = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

default-time-zone       = "Asia/Calcutta"

log_error           = "D:/Program Files/xampp/mysql/data/mysql.err"
pid_file            = "mysql.pid"
general_log         = 0
general_log_file    = "D:/Program Files/xampp/mysql/data/mysql.log"
slow_query_log      = 0
slow_query_log_file = "D:/Program Files/xampp/mysql/data/mysql-slow.log"

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
#
#skip-networking
enable-named-pipe

# Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
#log-bin = mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
#binlog_format = mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     = <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     = <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password = <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     = <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin         = mysql-bin

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
tmpdir           = "D:/Program Files/xampp/tmp/"
#log-update      = "D:/Program Files/xampp/tmp/mysql"

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir            = "D:/Program Files/xampp/mysql/data/"
innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir       = "D:/Program Files/xampp/mysql/data/"
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size            = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 254M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

but still i am getting same error. I am trying to restore mysqldump of size 160MB which has many BLOB contents .

Comment: Did you restart the MySQL service after making the change?

Comment: Backup may be corrupt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an explanation of how to solve that http://eppand.com/solution-to-mysql-error-2006-in-xampp/

Comment: Mine is set to 1 billion: max_allowed_packet=1000000000, and still I get the error. Now I am going to try 1 trillion: max_allowed_packet=1000000000000.

Answer (score 22):

Try changing the `max_allowed_packet` setting to a larger value in the server.

Open "my.ini/cnf", located in your MySQL installation folder, and under `[mysqld]` section change "`max_allowed_packet = 64M`" and don't forget to restart the server. You can check the value by executing:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs, there is untouched config files for XAMPP:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8SVZZwmcOIYNjdwbkluUTJERTA&usp=sharing